# Detect click position on Android

Tags: android, events, 2d, android-canvas

I have an Android app consisting of a 2D videogame. At certain moment, three elements show at the top of the screen. What I need to do is detect when one of these three elements is clicked and depending of which one is clicked, do certain operations.

Here's a gif trying to explain what I want to achieve https://gyazo.com/292f5dbb3f9fea018a687386f2732487

Comment: Why you don't use View.OnClickListener to detect item click ?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit further the OnClickListener? I am very new in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain about OnClickListener, i'll show you an example.

In my layout, suppose i have three buttons called btn1, btn2, btn3

```
findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //Inform the user the button has been clicked
       Toast.makeText(this, "Button1 clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   }
});

findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //Inform the user the button has been clicked
       Toast.makeText(this, "Button2 clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   }
});

findViewById(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //Inform the user the button has been clicked
       Toast.makeText(this, "Button3 clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   }
});
```

Credits: http://www.androiddevresources.com/guides/tutorial-how-to-implement-an-onclicklistener/